# hide label on doughnut chart of chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Thanks for the help in advance.I am using doughnut graph of chartjs.In it the percentage value labels are coming on the graph.Is there any way i can hide it.

[image]

```
 var category_doughnut_datas = [80,5,5,10];

var category_doughnut__data = {
  labels: ["Safe Zone", "Level 1","Level 2","Level 3"],
  };

var category_doughnut_options = {
  cutoutPercentage: 60,
  legend: {
    display: false,
    position: "top",
    paddingBottom: 16,
    align: "start",
    labels: {
      fontColor: "#555555",
      fontSize: 20,
      boxWidth: 0,
    },
  },
  tooltips: {
    displayColors: false,
  },
  responsive: true,
};
var dough_ctx = document.getElementById("overallStatus").getContext("2d");
if (dough_ctx) {
  var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(dough_ctx, {
    type: "doughnut",
    data: category_doughnut__data,
    options: category_doughnut_options,
  });
}
```

Comment: So you wanna hide the percentages `5%, 10%...` or what?

Comment: Could you show us your code? Just relevant part

Comment: @AdilBimzagh yes i want to hide that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you dont specify any options to draw it on the chart in your options and its not default chart.js behaviour I expect you defined it as defaults somewhere, in which case you can in your options object in the plugins section specify `datalabels: false` to stop it from rendering:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
Chart.defaults.plugins.datalabels.color = '#fff';
Chart.defaults.plugins.datalabels.formatter = (value, ctx) => {
  let sum = 0;
  let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
  dataArr.map(data => {
    sum += data;
  });
  let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2) + "%";
  return percentage;
};

const options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: false // Removing this line shows the datalabels again
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`options.plugins.datalabels: false` should be mentioned.

Without it, the value is set to be true by default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).